# OutofMemoryError while trying to construct Bitmap from byte Array

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-image

I am fetching byte array from blob type while is stored in db, it works for small image but when image size is more than 200kb it gives me an error of outofmemoryerror.
What should i do to overcome such error

photo is my byte array

```
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(photo);
            Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(theImage, 100,80, true);
            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapScaled);
            imgPath.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            imgPath.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
```

Logcat error

```
05-06 15:55:38.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 15:55:38.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2647): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-06 15:55:38.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
05-06 15:55:38.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
05-06 15:55:38.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:549)
05-06 15:55:38.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at com.example.hotelmenu.RevisedMainMenu.displayMenu(RevisedMainMenu.java:655)
05-06 15:55:38.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at com.example.hotelmenu.RevisedMainMenu.onClick(RevisedMainMenu.java:615)
```

Comment: There is a lot of advice on google and SO, have you searched at all /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image size does not matter. What's matter is width and height.  Infact your Bitmap instance will retains `width*height*4` bytes. If you are getting `OOM` I will suggest you to downsample your `Bitmap`  .

Also

```
 Bitmap theImage= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
 Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(theImage, 100,80, true);
```

in the snippet you provide, after `bitmapScaled` is created, theImage in never used. You should recycle it calling

```
theImage.recycle().
```

Edit. This snippet will create a bitmap 1/4 wider and higher than original

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inSampleSize = 4;
 Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options );
```

Comment: -blackbelt ok can you please suggest me an example.

Comment: example for what ? Downsamplig the bitmap?

Comment: I am new to this i dont understand the term Downsamplig .. All i need is how could the overcome this error of outofMemory, and reason for this error

Comment: – blackbelt Yup thnks dude